# Visual Studio Code run Chrome, Chrome opens but connection refused

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, ubuntu-21.04

OS Ubuntu 21 (fresh install). Trying to start a Flutter/Dart tutorial using Visual Studio. Started a basic flutter project. Added Chrome as web device. Click run, chrome opens window but refuses to connect to port 8080.  I tested my localhost is working by installing Apache2 and can open startup page at port 80 no problem.  Closed Apache.  Retried from VSCode with port in launch.js set to 80, still could not connect.  I get a Chrome window with this message: This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

stock launch.js that was created with new flutter project...
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"type": "pwa-chrome",
"request": "launch",
"name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
"url": "http://localhost:8080",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
]
}

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the Visual Code Insider snap package and it works now.